# Can't upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 "cannot verify changelogs.ubuntu.com's certificate"

Tags: upgrade

I'm unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04.

I verified 19.04 was officially released, and appears in https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release.

When I run `sudo update-manager -c`, I get the following error message in the terminal (though the GUI just happily reports no updates are available):

> Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

I tried accessing the file with `wget changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release`
and got the following error message

> --2019-04-20 21:01:27--  https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
>   Resolving changelogs.ubuntu.com (changelogs.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.95.15, 2001:67c:1560:8008::11
>
> Connecting to changelogs.ubuntu.com (changelogs.ubuntu.com)|91.189.95.15|:443... connected.
>
> ERROR: cannot verify changelogs.ubuntu.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
>     Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
>
> To connect to changelogs.ubuntu.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

Though when I tried accessing the same file with `curl changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release`, the download succeeded (I read somewhere its certificates might be more up-to-date).

As I've seen suggested, I restarted my system multiple times, waited more than 24 hours, and tried deleting the local `~/.cache/update-manager-core/meta-release`, but that didn't help.

I verified the site's certificates on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=changelogs.ubuntu.com&latest and got an A+.

I'd prefer solutions that don't require me to get the file over http instead of https.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I solved my problem:

I downloaded the meta-release file over https using curl: `curl http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release > ~/.cache/update-manager-core/meta-release`.

Then I edited the local `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` to be:

```
# default location for the meta-release file

[METARELEASE]
#URI = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
URI = file:///home/YOUR-USERNAME/.cache/update-manager-core/meta-release
URI_LTS = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
URI_UNSTABLE_POSTFIX = -development
URI_PROPOSED_POSTFIX = -proposed
```

Note you'll have to change YOUR-USERNAME to the appropriate value on your system.

The upgrade works smoothly now!

Comment: just a personal nitpick question; could you possibly replace the username slot with the USER environment variable, and have it work? part of me doubts it since security and i don't know what type of file ``/etc/update-manager/meta-release`` is, but i figured i'd ask

Comment: @EarthToAccess, I tried specifying the username as $USER$ and as {USER} now - doesn't seem to work.

Comment: hmm, interesting. it probably doesn't work as a security measure, otherwise you could create a sh script to modify things like ``/etc/update-manage/meta-release`` and destroy an install.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because openssl is looking for a certificate at `/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem`, which is invalid. I followed [this person's solution](https://yaleman.org/post/2018/2018-09-06-openssl-ca-trust-weirdness/) of using `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem`.

This issue affects other applications like wget.

Comment: this solved the issue for me at least (trying to update from 20.04 to 22.04)

Answer (score 2):

**Update (2023-03-22):**
I found an easier way - just remove all the certificates, and ask Ubuntu to re-download them:

```bash
# Make a backup first
mkdir ~/old-certs/
sudo mv /etc/ssl/certs/* ~/old-certs/

# Create a directory for Java certificates, as the below command needs it
sudo mkdir /etc/ssl/certs/java

# update /etc/ssl/certs (remove symlinks) and ca-certificates.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

---

I had the exact same issue. I followed the [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410613/14987) by [@WhiteKnight](https://askubuntu.com/users/210187/whiteknight), but with a different result. Using `strace` to see why `wget` doesn't work:

```
strace -e trace=open,openat wget https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
```

Somewhere in the logs, I saw that the following file was opened:

```
/usr/lib/ssl/certs/8d33f237.0
```

Checking the above file with OpenSSL, I noted that it's an expired certificate for `Let's Encrypt`. So I just moved the file to `/tmp`, and tried the `wget` command again. This time, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks @M.S.Dousti: This also solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My machines are configured to use an apt-cache, which I fixed by adding a PassThroughPattern to my /etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf

```
PassThroughPattern: ^changelogs\.ubuntu\.com:443$
```

If you already have a PassThroughPattern, you'll need to edit that, e.g. if you currently have:

```
PassThroughPattern: soandso.com:443
```

change it to

```
PassThroughPattern: ^(soandso\.com|changelogs\.ubuntu\.com):443$
```

If this doesn't help, you may want to try the following:

```
$ ( sed -ne 's/^ *\(from\|import.*\)/\1/p' \
    /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade \
    echo "init_proxy()" \
    echo "MetaReleaseCore.DEBUG = True" \
    echo "MetaReleaseCore(useProposed=True)"\
  ) | python3
```

This should give you additional information on what is causing it to fail.