# "No new release found" on 16.04 when 18.04.4 is available

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I just upgraded a 14.04 server to 16.04 using the standard `do-release-upgrade` process.  Now I'm getting "No new release found" when trying to run it again to get to 18.04.

Things tried:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`
- `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
- `sudo apt full-upgrade`
- `sudo do-release-upgrade` ("No new release found.")
- `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` ("Upgrades to the development release are only available from the latest supported release.")
- `sudo do-release-upgrade -p` ("No new release found.")
- `wget http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release` (successfully gets the file, it shows the correct data including the 18.04 info)
- `sudo apt install update-manager-core` ("update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:16.04.17).")
- `vim /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` (prompt is set to "lts" as expected)

Questions:

- Why isn't 18.04 being found and offered to upgrade?  I don't understand how `do-release-upgrade` works under the hood and why it'd throw "no new release found" when it is successfully accessing the meta-release file, the file has the correct data and there is a newer LTS release with a point version out.
- How do I upgrade this machine? What is the best and safest workaround?

Comment: Which "development release" appears on `do-release-upgrade -d`? Probably updates are disabled in Software & Updates.

Comment: It doesn't show any release.  Just says that error.  Are you talking about the GUI Software & Updates?  This machine doesn't have a GUI installed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try installing the ca-certificates package and then running 'do-release-upgrade'. The fix for this issue is in progress you can follow it via https://launchpad.net/bugs/1796940.

Comment: `ca-certificates` is already installed and up-to-date.  Looks like the usual indicator of that issue is `Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings`, which is not the result I'm experiencing.

Comment: Could you paste the output of "DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=1 do-release-upgrade"?

Comment: You're a hero.  It's a cert error and it's because of the corporate content filtering.

Comment: If you wanted to post an answer explaining the use of DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER, I'd gladly accept it.  I googled around and didn't come across that, and it's exactly the sort of additional info I was looking for to debug that extremely opaque error.

Comment: Hi @thunderblaster  how do you solved the certificate issue? 
I have to patch a machine I inherited at work (installed by someone else) an currently using 20.04 but it throws the error "result of meta-release download: '<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)>'"when I run the DEBUG_UPDATE _MANAGER=1 do-release-upgrade line

Comment: @AndrésParada it's been a couple of years now, but the issue as I recall it was that our Palo Alto firewalls were presenting a cert signed by an internal CA that my Ubuntu machine didn't trust so that the firewalls could MITM the traffic and I had to request my network administrators disable that functionality for this server.  You could likely add the presented cert to the OS truststore if you knew the firewall was just sniffing traffic and would allow your HTTP requests without blocking.  Big cavaet: you need to be absolutely certain it is your corporate firewalling MITMing your traffic.

Comment: @thunderblaster thanks, I fixed with this https://askubuntu.com/a/1410613/265501 in case someone else needs it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help someone:

In my particular case, when I tried to upgrade from Xenial to Bionic and used my own apt-mirror with Bionic repositories, I got an issue that `do-release-upgrade` can't find any new releases:

```
root@<my_host>:~# do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

I found a [source code](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/xenial/main/all/python3-update-manager/1:16.04.3/file/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py) to enable the debug mode:

```
root@<my_host>:/root# export DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=True
```

and determined my root cause, an expired certificate on apt-mirror host:

```
root@<my_host>:/usr/bin# do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
MetaRelease.__init__() useDevel=False useProposed=False
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: https://<my-apt-mirror>/meta-release
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: https://<my-apt-mirror>/meta-release-lts
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: -development
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: -proposed
metarelease-uri: https://<my-apt-mirror>/meta-release-lts
MetaRelease.download()
result of meta-release download: '<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>'
NO self.metarelease_information
No new release found.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a failure to download the meta release file, due to firewall, tls configuration, ca-certificates etc.

The easiest fix I found is opening the file /etc/update-manager/meta-release, manually downloading the file for URI_LTS and uploading it somewhere else preferrably where it can be accessed without https, and putting that new URL into that file:
URI_LTS = http://my.own.server.example.com/copy-of-meta-release-lts

After that the upgrade worked just fine for me.

Comment: Hello. Read the answer to the question it has already been solved and this was not the answer. As written your answer is not complete as well. From your answer. <due to firewall, tls configuration, ca-certificates etc.> Just some guesses. Sorry.