# Trying to update a server from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: server, updates

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a hosting provider. I want to upgrade the server to 20.04 LTS. I have done all the normal updates and taken a snapshot of the server but when I run sudo do-release-update -d or without the -d I get a message that it failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts-development.
I have changed the release-upgrades to Prompt=normal which still fails to find the
meta-release-lts-development file. Am I doing something wrong? How do I achieve my objective?

Requested info

```
Alan@vps45143457:~$ sudo r do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
Alan@vps45143457:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d   
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
No new release found.
Alan@vps45143457:~$ exit
logout
```

@guiverc I was puzzled by your response. What does *jammy* mean?
I am only beginning to understand Ubuntu. I do not know why the 'r' is in the text provided but the response is what you see.

@guiverc I should have thought of that.
However it does not answer the question about updating to 20.04.x why has the system not found the meta-release file? I tried to open it in a browser and got 404. I then opened the holding folder and in it found the meta-release file. So is the problem unsolvable?
I suppose I could wait until 22.04.1 is released and try the upgrade again!

FINAL UPDATE
The hosting provider Hostinger has stated that it is not possible to update the current version of Ubuntu server. I will have to rebuild the whole website installing a newer Ubuntu available from their list. The implication is that even if I did that I would not be able to upgrade that to 22.04 or any other version.
Needless to say I am not satisfied and am looking for a new hosting provider!

Comment: Why are you using `do-release-upgrade -d` ; the *development* release is *jammy* or 22.04 and not 20.04.  Ubuntu 20.04 is *stable* & we're well past the 20.04.1 stage (before 20.04.1 the `-d` is required), thus `-d` isn't correct (current support level for *focal* is 20.04.3). Your pasted detail doesn't look correct; as after `sudo r` I'd expect an error not it acting like the command was `do-release-upgrade` (*when it was not in your paste*)

Comment: Jammy is the codename of ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Your first listed command is `sudo r do-release-upgrade -d` ie. the command executed is `r` and it's passed the options `do-release-upgrade -d`.   `r` is not a valid command thus I'd expect an error at that command not the output you provided thus something is wrong if your paste is correct. All Ubuntu release have a *codename*, 18.04 is *bionic*, 20.04 is *focal* and *jammy* is the codename of what will be 22.04 on release (it's not 22.04 yet as it's still in *development* which is what the `-d` option for `do-release-upgrade` is for. Ubuntu releases are known by the *codename* until *stable*

Comment: Have you tried `sudo do-release-upgrade`? This is the correct command to release upgrade.  Make sure your system is up-to-date with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` first.

Comment: Also, I don't get a 404 when I try to run any of these URLs in a browser. Perhaps the problem really is with your server's network or ISP?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly these steps worked for me on two systems Intel 4790 and Ryzen 2500G:

You need to do a releas upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 and then from 20.04 to 22.04

Step by step:

1. tappend these to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (this is an important step that fixes the OP question, without this you cannot upgrade packages, and dist-upgrade, and without that you cannot do the releas upgrade):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
```

2. Now on the following steps you would be needing to answer with OK and y on a few questions so make sure you look once in a while on your display, you would be needing a few restarts and it takes anywhere from half an hour to 1-2 hours, update the package list:

   sudo apt update

now upgrade packages:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

followed by dist upgrade

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

then remove all packages from your system by entering the following command (this is optional):

sudo apt autoremove

install the update-manager-core  package by running the following command, in case you don't have it already:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

after that, you cand run the release upgrade utility. To do this by the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

after this is ready you have 20.04, once you have 20.04 (check with `lsb_release -a`) run one more time:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

after this is ready you should have 22.04

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem` as seen here ->
https://askubuntu.com/a/1410613/265501